# Access List of Parameters from Within an Action

Tags: .net-core, api-design

I would like to be able to generically access a list\dictionary of parameters from within an action. I know its possible to do this from within an ActionFilter by using:

```
ActionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters
```

But, I can't figure out a way to access that same list from within the action itself.

Backstory:
The end goal is for all of my actions to call the same function. The function will accept a stored proc name, and a list of parameters, then execute the stored proc using the supplied parameters. I have created each action so that the actions parameters are the same name\type as the stored proc parameters. Using this setup, I want to be able to just send the list of parameters associated with the action to a single generic call.

I have tried using:

```
HttpContext.Request.Query
```

But, that won't work, because I could have some action parameters that aren't required and have a default, these don't show up in the http query, and I still need them to be passed into my generic function.

Answer (score 0):

"ModelState" is what I was looking for, it has everything I need, including the default values of the parameters that weren't in the query string.